# Generating JavaDoc for JUnit test classes works in Eclipse but not Intellij

Tags: eclipse, testing, intellij-idea, junit, javadoc

So I am currently creating test classes (JUnit5) for my program. I seem to be running into an issue when trying to generate the JavaDoc html through IntelliJ, but generating with Eclipse for the exact same class works just fine.The error I get from IntelliJ is vague to say the least: "error: No public or protected classes found to document."

The little information I could find about generating JavaDoc for JUnit classes seems to be 10 years old at least and not quite helpful.Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and if yes any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?

Generated JavaDoc with Eclipse (same project, same POM) works fine but IntelliJ throws and error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the IDE main menu `Tools | Generate JavaDoc` to generate the JavaDoc, you could change the `Visibility level` to `private`, and the IDEA should able to generate the JavaDoc for your tests now.

If your tests' classes don't have any public/protected modifier using another `protected` visibility level will fail.